# Dojo dgrid: Filter data from store with diffrent fields when I click on filter button

Tags: dojo, store, dgrid, dstore

I am using 'dgrid/Grid' and dstore/RequestMemory for creating grid and storing data. Now I want to filter data according to values in the fields(see img). I am not sure how to filter data when using simple Dgrid and dstore.

```
 var structure = [{
            label : "Value Date",
            field : "valueDate"
        }, {
            id: "currencyCol",
            label : "Currency",
            field : "currency"
        }, {
            label : "Nostro",
            field : "nostroAgent"
        }];

        var store= new RequestMemory({
            target: 'getReportData',
            idProperty: "cashflowId",
            headers: structure
        });
        // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
        var grid = new(declare([Grid, Pagination, Selection]))({
            collection: store,
            columns: structure,
            loadingMessage: 'Loading data...',
            noDataMessage: 'No results found.',
            minRowsPerPage: 50,
        }, 'grid');
        grid.startup(); 

      on(document.getElementById("filter"), "click", function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            grid.set('collection', store.filter({                   
                **currencyCol: "AED"**
                      .
                      .
                      .
            }));
```

[image: Dgrid Page]
Any help would be appreciated or suggest if I use some diffrent store or grid.

Comment: It looks like you have the beginning of the idea here already and just need to put multiple filters together.  If you haven't seen dstore's [Filtering docs](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/1.1/docs/Collection.md#filtering) yet, they might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for my question. On filter button click I have written all my filtering logic and the final store will set to dgrid:

```
        on(document.getElementById("filter"), "click", function(event) {

            var store= new RequestMemory({
                target: 'getReportData',
                idProperty: "cashflowId",
                headers: structure
            });

            var from=dijit.byId('from').value;
            var to=dijit.byId('to').value;
            var curr=dijit.byId('currency').value;
            var nos=dijit.byId('nostro').value;
            var authStatus=dijit.byId('authStatus').value;
            var filterStore;
            var finalStore=store;
            var filter= new store.Filter();
            var dateToFindFrom;
            var dateToFindTo;

            if (from != "" && from !== null) {

                var yyyy = from.getFullYear().toString();
                var mm = ((from.getMonth()) + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
                var dd  = from.getDate().toString();

                if(mm <= 9){
                    mm= "0" + mm;
                }
                if(dd <= 9){
                    dd= "0" + dd;
                }

                dateToFindFrom =yyyy + mm + dd;

                filterStore= filter.gte('valueDate', dateToFindFrom);
                finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);

            }
            if (to != "" && to !== null) {
                var yyyy = to.getFullYear().toString();
                var mm = ((to.getMonth()) + 1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
                var dd  = to.getDate().toString();

                if(mm <= 9){
                    mm= "0" + mm;
                }
                if(dd <= 9){
                    dd= "0" + dd;
                }


                dateToFindTo =yyyy + mm + dd;

                filterStore= filter.lte('valueDate', dateToFindTo); //.lte('valueDate', dateToFindTo);
                finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
            }

            if(curr != "" && curr !== null) {
                filterStore= filter.eq('currency', curr);
                finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
            }
            if(nos != "" && nos !== null) {
                filterStore= filter.eq('nostroAgent',nos);
                finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
            }

            if(authStatus != "" && authStatus !== null) {
                    if (authStatus=='ALL') {
                        var both= [true, false];
                        filterStore= filter.in('approved', both);
                        finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
                    } else if (authStatus=='Authorised Only') {
                        filterStore= filter.eq('approved', true);
                        finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
                    } else if (authStatus=='Unauthorised Only') {
                        filterStore= filter.eq('approved', false);
                        finalStore=finalStore.filter(filterStore);
                    };
            };
            grid.set('collection', finalStore);

        });
```